# Nested for loop not proceeding to the inner loop

Tags: java, list, loops

I have this nested for loop to add values to an array, but for some reason, the internal for loop is being skipped

```
for(int i = attack_pos[0] + 2; i < attack_pos[0] + 5; i++) {
     radius.add(i);
     for (int j = attack_pos[1] + 1; j < attack_pos[1] - 1; j ++) {
        radius.add(j);
        radius.add(i);
    }
            
}
```

Comment: There is only one loop in the code snippet. Also, you need to explain what attack_pos array holds.

Comment: It will never run because your loop condition will never be true.  Take out the array  from `int j = attack_pos[1] + 1; j < attack_pos[1] - 1;` and look at your code `int j = 1; j < -1` is your loop condition, of course `1` is not less than `-1`

Comment: It is proceeding to the inner loop but that iteration ends immediately because your initial state fails the test.

Answer (score 0):

say attack_pos[1] = 10

initial: `j = attack_pos[1] + 1`

`j` starts at 10+1=11

condition: `j < attack_pos[1] - 1`

`j` is never less than 10-1=9

therefore the condition of the inner loop is never satisfied.